# django channels session resetting

Tags: django, session, channel

I am trying to work with active users and sessions with channels.
However often my channel gives a AnonymousUser while i am logged in. @login required on the normal view)

Also on every call my session seems to save.

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    print(message['headers'])
    drop_map(message)
    # message.user.active_map works like it is supposed to
    message.user.active_map.websocket_group.add(message.reply_channel)

def ws_message(message):
    payload = json.loads(message['text'])
    payload['reply_channel'] = message.content['reply_channel']
    Channel("maps.receive").send(payload)

@channel_session_user
@catch_client_error
def map_background(message):
    # Now message.user is anonymous user and code crashes
    map_obj = message.user.active_map
    character = message.user.active_character
    grid = map_obj.template.static_grid.slice_grid(character.location.x, character.location.y, message.user.settings)
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            "action": "load_background",
            "name": map_obj.name,
            "grid": grid,
        }),
    })
```

At the ws_connect it all works as it should and i get my logged in user.
However when I make a call on map_background, suddenly my user is an anonymous user. I use redis as my channel backend.

headers: [[b'cache-control', b'no-cache'], [b'accept-encoding', b'gzip, deflate'], [b'cookie', b'csrftoken=mlI5ODljY3eJ3Le1dPnv1VrmZznAVCbo7XU9JAIK8bb8urjbcEimsZRUqczCzzdI; sessionid=druv90lxnz36yahnr7zcybojh5xlzdl2'], [b'connection', b'keep-alive, Upgrade'], [b'sec-websocket-version', b'13'], [b'origin', b'http://localhost:8000'], [b'sec-websocket-extensions', b'permessage-deflate'], [b'host', b'localhost:8000'], [b'pragma', b'no-cache'], [b'upgrade', b'websocket'], [b'accept-language', b'en-US,en;q=0.5'], [b'user-agent', b'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'], [b'sec-websocket-key', b'mx5wy9w8HxH2dQ6ls5/rUg=='], [b'accept', b'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8']]

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer? I have this very same problem

Comment: It has top do with the reconnecting websocket. You have to work from cookie. Not sure yet how, but that is the issue

Comment: Also a socket session only lives as long as the socket is alive. Instead of the http session that is persistant